# Why the command isn't being executed in SSH? Python

Tags: python, windows, ssh

I have the following code snipped, to allow executing across two Windows machines. I installed `copssh` to work as a ssh server in a windows machine, and I'm trying to get it to work ...

```
    cmd = "python --version"
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
    client.connect("myhost",username="admin", password="adminpass")

    print "restarting machine ... "
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
    print stdout.readlines()
```

when the following code is executed, I get:

```
C:\wcat>python main.py
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.11.0-py2.7.egg\paramiko\client.py:95: U
serWarning: Unknown ssh-rsa host key for 192.168.2.4: 7bf6ba243a3daaa994e0b42067
9cfb30
  (key.get_name(), hostname, hexlify(key.get_fingerprint())))
restarting machine ...
[]
```

which returns nothing ... even doing simple Windows commands like `cd C:\ && dir` is returning me `[]`. I'm also doing the same thing from the machine I'm ssh-ing to the other machine, and it works, but the way around isn't ... what could be the possible causes?

Comment: @Kyle `Stderr <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 1 (open) window=2097152 -> <
paramiko.Transport at 0x2a03bd0L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open c
hannel(s))>>>`

Comment: @philippe: That looks like it's just a `repr` of stderr: if you read from the file (e.g., `print stderr.read()`), do you get anything?

Comment: @Thanatos ... when I print stderr.read() I get nothing ... `print stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()` returns 127 ... what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to load the system host keys in addition to setting the missing host key policy.

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `python --version` and stream output to stderr. You can easily check it with

```
python --version >> out 2> err
```